# Laravel Echo receiving frames but not triggering

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm trying to broadcast a simple event using Redis, Laravel Echo, Laravel Echo Server, and socket.io.
I've got everything in place on the client side. The message is indeed being broadcasted and laravel echo server is picking up on it.

On chat.dev/ I have the client joining. On chat.dev/new I have the event being broadcast.

```
[5:14:31 PM] - HvEq_a12YnQFJGFiAAAE joined channel: chat
Channel: chat
Event: message.created
CHANNEL chat
```

So it seems like everything is working. On the client side, I'm including socket.io and it is finding it.

```
<script src="//{{ Request::getHost() }}:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Then I'm running

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});


window.Echo.channel('chat')
    .listen('.message.created', (e) => {
        console.log("Got message");
    });
```

But nothing is being logged to the console. Why?

After much fiddling, the frame is now being received. BUT, .listen isn't capturing it.

```
42["message.created", "chat", {,…}]
0
:
"message.created"
1
:
"chat"
2
:
{,…}
message
:
{id: 23, body: "Modified", created_at: "2017-07-19 01:11:18", updated_at: "2017-07-19 01:11:18"}
socket
:
null
```

Here's the respective Reddit and GitHub issue links.

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/6o4bqm/laravel_echo_not_picking_up_on_event)
[GitHub](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/187)

Comment: And before anyone says anything, yes I've tried "message.created" without the initial dot. Nothing

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issues, i created a separate custom event and on broadcast function i did this: return new Channel('test_channel'); instead of "private channel" in laravel 5.4 and also, please check your .env has BROADCAST_DRIVER defined.

Comment: I am returning a regular Channel, not a private channel. Also I do have my broadcast driver enabled. Like the frames are arriving in the client side, but for whatever reason Laravel Echo isn't picking up on it!

Comment: watch this, i think this will help you: